# YouTube Data API: authenticate as a resource owner

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I have a task to import video details of videos, uploaded on YouTube.

I have an account, that is the video owner. I have setup credentials in the console: https://console.developers.google.com/project/XXXXX/apiui/credential. I have created OAuth Service Account there.

Later in the script I am using the code from documentation (v3 version of the API):

```
    $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $clientEmail,
        [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
        ],
        $privateKeyContents
    );
    $this->client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

    /** @var Google_Auth_OAuth2 $auth */
    $auth = $this->client->getAuth();

    if ($auth->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $auth->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    }
```

Authentication works ok. I've attached logger to Google Client and I can see `Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXX` header passed with each request.

But the problem is, that it seems, YouTube does not recognize this authentication as an authentication of an actual resource owner. For example, if I request Video Snippet, it is returned without tags (tags can be seen only by owner on some reason).

If I make the same request from here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?hl=ru it works flawlessly.

What can be the problem?

The request in logs looks like this:

```
[2015-06-08 14:50:02] name.DEBUG: OAuth2 authentication [] []
[2015-06-08 14:50:02] name.DEBUG: cURL request {"url":"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=id%2Csnippet&channelId=XXXXXXXXXXXX&maxResults=50","method":"GET","headers":{"authorization":"Bearer ya29.XXXXX-XXXXXX","accept-encoding":"gzip"},"body":null} []
```

This differs from what I can see if tracing the request Google Javascript client makes on Documentation page. The domain is different, Javascript client passes more headers etc.

How do I make it work with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You should add [onBehalfofContentOwner](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#onBehalfOfContentOwner) parameter to your request to show yourself as the content owner.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a YouTube content partner.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have been using Google Service Account credentails for authentication. The API call needs to be made after authenticating as "Client ID for web application" rather than a service account. After you have created a new set of credentials for web application, authenticate as follows:

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);//This Uri should match exactly to what you had given in Google Developer Console while generating Client ID/Secret

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: That video import of mine is automated. I cannot use any redirection URLs there. OAuth flow you described is for human interaction only.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny: i understand but the API call you are trying to make needs human interaction. I took the code example from [API page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?hl=ru). This is why, API calls succeed when you try it is using API Explorer. Since you are trying to get a user's resource (Videos in this case), an explicit authentication by the user is mandatory.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarification, but still this doesn't solve my problem. I need to authenticate as a resource owner using PHP and automated script.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny: Since video resource is associated to a specific user, so there is not way that you can access this data without manual OAuth workflow requiring explicit user access. What you can do is save the user Access_Token and Refresh Token on first OAuth cycle and then use the same for subsequent requests to API, virtually indefinitely using the same access/refresh token.

Comment: What I do not understand is why I can't ;) I am still using Google_Auth_OAuth2 flow just with another flow.

Comment: OAuth2 has two variances. Two-legged authentication and three-legged authentication.The API you are trying to call needs three-legged authentication because its access a user's private resource (Video list). Whenever an API accesses a user's private resource, it can not be done with Service Account authentication. It requires OAuth Cycle with user explicitly granting access to your application to access user's private resources.

Comment: But I can create resources using two-legged oauth. I guess this should require the same permission level as viewing existing ones.

Comment: What kind of resource were you able to create using two-legged oauth? You can not create a user's private resource with this approach. You need the user impersonation, which is done by three-legged oauth.